Plotly won't produce a graph on python spyder/anaconda IDE
I have the following code that should produce spheres of infinite potential value at some specific points that represent atoms in a periodic silicon lattice, furthermore, it should also produce a surface of variable color, that represents the value for the calculated electric potential of that lattice due to the atoms in a cationic state.
That said the problem I'm having is that after all the compilation no graph will show on the screen, and no problem has appeared in the console for troubleshooting.
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

mesh = 11
x = np.linspace(0,1,mesh,True)
value = np.random.randn(mesh,mesh,mesh)
Vmin = value.min()
Vmax = value.max()

# Plot the graph as a volume plot
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Volume(
    x=x.flatten(),
    y=x.flatten(),
    z=x.flatten(),
    value= value.flatten(),
    isomin = Vmin,
    isomax = Vmax,
    opacity=0.1, # needs to be small to see through all surfaces
    surface_count=25, # needs to be a large number for good volume rendering
    ))

fig.show()

I have already tried to analyze the variables tab and all of then have the expected values.
Upon further research I've encountered the official plotly page that recommended that I reinstalled plotly via terminal, and so I did, just to get nothing as reward.
A few days ago I've tried to create another post here that referred to the same code but a different problem, and since the problem was solved with a simple reboot of the IDE I've decided to delete the post, since it was no longer necessary and the problem has changed in to another totally different, or so I think.

TIP: create a [mre] no one here wants to wait for a minute of simulation compute just to expose a graph window not showing up. Just use dummy data...

@Julien thanks for the tip, I've updated the code in the post so the mesh would be only 10 points/axis and thus the compilation time dropped to a few milliseconds.

Keep removing all code irrelevant with your current issue: graph not showing up. See my edit.

Does this answer your question? Plotly: Figure window doesn't appear using Spyder

@Julien kinda.
Now the graph does render, but only the axis, it does not show any data plotted.
